# What is the analytic interpretation for Tensorflow custom gradient?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, gradient-descent

In the official [tf.custom_gradient](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/custom_gradient) documentation it shows how to define custom gradients for `log(1 + exp(x))`

```py
@tf.custom_gradient
def log1pexp(x):
  e = tf.exp(x)
  def grad(dy):
    return dy * (1 - 1 / (1 + e))
  return tf.math.log(1 + e), grad
```

When `y = log(1 + exp(x))`, analytically the derivative comes out to be `dy/dx = (1 - 1 / (1 + exp(x)))`.

However in the code `def grad` says its `dy * (1 - 1 / (1 + exp(x)))`.
`dy/dx = dy * (1 - 1 / (1 + exp(x)))` is not a valid equation. While `dx = dy * (1 - 1 / (1 + exp(x)))` is wrong as it should be the reciprocal.

What does the `grad` function equate to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out. The `dy` should be called `upstream_gradient` or `upstream_dy_dx`.

By chain rule we know that

[image: chain rule]

where `dx[i]/dx[i+1]` is the gradient of the current function.

So `dy` is the product of all the gradients upstream before this function.

[image]

So, if you forget to multiply the `dy` it is effectively the same as [tf.stop_gradient](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/stop_gradient)

Here is a code which demos this. Full notebook [here](https://github.com/Ghost---Shadow/differentiable-programming-handbook/blob/master/notebooks/custom-gradient.ipynb)

```py
@tf.custom_gradient
def foo(x):
    tf.debugging.assert_rank(x, 0)

    def grad(dy_dx_upstream):
        dy_dx = 2 * x
        dy_dx_downstream = dy_dx * dy_dx_upstream
        tf.print(f'x={x}\tupstream={dy_dx_upstream}\tcurrent={dy_dx}\t\tdownstream={dy_dx_downstream}')
        return dy_dx_downstream
    
    y = x ** 2
    tf.print(f'x={x}\ty={y}')
    
    return y, grad


x = tf.constant(2.0, dtype=tf.float32)

with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape:
    tape.watch(x)
    y = foo(foo(foo(x))) # y = x ** 8

tf.print(f'\nfinal dy/dx={tape.gradient(y, x)}')
```

Output

```
x=2.0   y=4.0
x=4.0   y=16.0
x=16.0  y=256.0
x=16.0  upstream=1.0    current=32.0        downstream=32.0
x=4.0   upstream=32.0   current=8.0     downstream=256.0
x=2.0   upstream=256.0  current=4.0     downstream=1024.0

final dy/dx=1024.0
```

Answer (score 0):

The extra `dy` you are looking at is the value of activation itself. Because the optimizer equation if you look at requires you multiply the gradient with the output value. Hence, this is why that has been done.

Comment: How do you represent that as an analytical equation? If it is the value of the activation, then should it be `y` instead of `dy` ?

Comment: It will be `dy` because it tells us the rate of change of y.

Comment: So, it is `dy/dx at x = x_0` where `x_0` was the input?